# Trouble connecting to TFS in one environment

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am having trouble connecting to TFS on my Azure development machine. The connection issue started happening this morning. Prior to today, it had been working perfectly. This is my work's TFS server which I know I have access to and that my credentials are valid and working. I have confirmed this by connecting to TFS via a web browser and on other machines via Visual Studio 2012. Only the Azure box seems to be affected.

Details about the machine:

- Windows Server 2008
- SQL Server 2012
- VS2012 w/update 3
- IE10

I have tried connecting on and off the work VPN, with the http and https endpoints that are available.

Here are the steps I have taken to try to remedy the issue:

- Updated VS2012 to update 3
- Cleared all cache and stored passwords in IE10
- Reset IE10 to default settings
- Cleared all TFS stored credentials in the windows credential manager
- Cleared all Visual Studio cache files - TFS cache, VS cache, etc...
  basically the steps in [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx)
- Reboot the VM multiple times
- Verified that I can access TFS through IE10 successfully on the VM

None of these had any effect. No matter what I do it seems that I cannot get a connection to TFS through VS2012. It keeps giving me the unauthorized / access denied errors.

Any more ideas of what to try? This was just working yesterday. The ONLY changes since yesterday are:

- Installation of some office applications - onenote, word, excel, etc.
  (it was working in conjunction with these changes yesterday)
- Update 3 installed for VS2012

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This is getting more interesting. It seems to be a bug with Visual Studio 2012. After submitting a ticket to my support team at work, I discovered that another coworker submitted a ticket with the exact same issue. His connection stopped working yesterday morning as well. He was also on an Azure VM running Server 2008 w/ Visual Studio 2012.

So after putting our heads together for about an hour and getting nowhere, I spun up another Azure VM to check the issue there. This time I created a Server 2012 w/ Visual Studio 2013 preview image. The connection to TFS worked on the first attempt.

This led us to try installing VS2013 preview on our VMs that were experiencing the issue. For both of us, after installing 2013, we were able to connect! What's really strange is that now VS2012 is working again as well... which is great, but I still have no idea what caused it.

When we were experiencing the problem, we had our IT support guy monitor the TFS build server AND the firewall that sits in front of it when we attempted to log in. He saw no login attempts getting through. So when it wasn't working, it appeared as though Visual Studio never even issued the login attempt to the server.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here? A bug in Visual Studio maybe? Or perhaps a windows update that affected me and my coworker at the same time? I can't think that the timing of this was a coincidence...